# selected drop box shows 2 values from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, implode

Hey I am having some trouble with my dropdown menu values that I retrieve from my database. I see two values instead of one.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") ;
$myDB = mysqli_select_db($con, "test");
$dbEnc = mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

$sqlSELECT = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT class FROM disastergroups'); 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="test">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSELECT)): ;?>
            <option><?php echo implode("\t", $row1); ?></option>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Data">
    </body>
</html>
```

The image below shows the duplicates in the dropdown menu... how do I fix this?

[image: CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the default of `resulttype`for [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) is `int $resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH` -> `mixed mysqli_fetch_array ( mysqli_result $result [, int $resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH ] )`. Change -

```
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSELECT)):
```

to

```
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSELECT, MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
```

Or, just use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlSELECT)):
```

so that you only get the 1 value, and you can remove the `implode()` ->

```
<option><?php echo $row1['class']; ?></option>
```

Comment: Try `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and then you will get the assoc array. Your answer will get a numerically indexed array so `$row1['class']` wont exist. It will be `$row1[0]`

Comment: Or use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` as param 2

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes, that was a copy error. Teaches me to not try to answer while cooking dinner for the kids

Comment: We guys cannot multi task, didn't a woman tell you that yet :)

Comment: yes, been told, but I don't like to be told what to do ;)

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you @se

Comment: Since I'm a new user I can not edit to correct your name @Sean sorry^

Comment: Glad to help. Make sure to make it as answered - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers